# Error on android emulator with Titanium

Tags: android-emulator, titanium

My Android Emulator used to work but now, when i'm emulating an app, appears the following errors in console:

```
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "C:\Android\android-sdk- windows\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 2596, in <module>
[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host, profiler_host=profiler_host)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 2243, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.copy_project_resources()
[ERROR]   File "C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 884, in copy_project_resources
[ERROR]     os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
[ERROR] WindowsError: [Error 145] El directorio no est� vac�o: 'C:\\Users\\hectorcedeno\\Documents\\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\\AppMovilPV\\planvitalapp-Titanium\\build\\android\\gen\\com\\galgomedia'
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems related to some problems with the build directory (permissions or storage issues), delete manually the build folder and try again.

```
'C:\\Users\\hectorcedeno\\Documents\\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\\AppMovilPV\\planvitalapp-Titanium\\build\\"
```

Comment: I'll do that if that is the solution

Comment: It is a quick fix, you need to figure out why the build folder doesn't clean automatically, and solve that.